# The Imaginary number

Tags: complex-numbers

Sometimes one writes $i^2=-1$ to characterize the imaginary number and sometimes as the root of $-1$. So when I resolve the first equation, I get for the imaginary number two roots of $-1$ and thus two complex numbers. I am confused.

Is it a question of definition or are the both definitions the same?

Thanks for your comment.

Comment: There are always two roots; also of $x^2+1=0$, namely $i$ and $-i$.

Comment: The two roots are complex conjugates of one another. This is true in a more general sense: If you have a polynomial $p(x)$ with real coefficients, then any complex roots will come in conjugate pairs.

Comment: Say that $\sqrt{-1}$ represents one of the two solutions of $z^2=1$ and call this $i$. It does not matter which one you pick.  The other solution will then be $-i$.

Comment: The first characterisation doesn't say $i$ equals all solutions, just that it is some number satisfying $i^1=-1$. That $(-i)^2=-1$ as well, isn't relevant.

Answer (score 3):

Often people write that $i=\sqrt{-1}$ however this doesn't really mean anything as $\sqrt\cdot$ is only defined for non negative real numbers. One can think of the definition of $i$ like this:

> Start with the real numbers with the normal operations of addition and multiplication. Add to the reals a symbol $i$ and the rule that $i^2=-1$.

From this we can write numbers as a linear combination $a+bi$ for real $x$ and $y$ and we can derive the rules for complex addition and multiplication by the definition of $i$

It is true that in the complex numbers there are two solutions to the equation $z^2+1=0$ however we can't define $i$ by saying "start with the equation and find a solution" because no solution exists in the reals.

The other thing to note is that most things to do with the complex numbers have a lot of symmetry to do with conjugation, If you imagine drawing everything in reverse on an argand diagram (so up becomes down, anti-clockwise becomes clockwise and such like) then you will find that nothing actually changes and in that sense the choice of $i$ as opposed to $-i$ is not only not a real choice but also one that doesn't matter.

Comment: Your claim about $\sqrt{-1}$ being undefined is incorrect.  $\sqrt{x}$ is defined for all real x as the positive square root (the principal square root).   Ex. $\sqrt{-4}=2i$, $\sqrt{9}=3$, etc.   The man who introduced $i$ defined $i$ as $\sqrt{-1}$ (the principal square root of -1).  So this isn’t a false claim that people make.  In every textbook about introduction to $i$, you will see $i$ defined as $\sqrt{-1}$.

Comment: @RadialArmSaw often the first definition of something does not stick because it is not precise or useful enough. The foundation of analysis mostly comes from Cauchy (with epsilons and deltas) rather than Newton or Liebnitz. Typically in modern mathematics one defines the complex numbers as a field extension of the reals by introducing a formal variable $i$ such that $i^2=-1,$ that is, one considers the ring of polynomials in the formal variable $i$ with real coefficients, then quotients by the ideal $(i^2-1),$ then observes that this quotient ring is in fact a field (extension of $\Bbb R$).

Answer (score 0):

When you write $\sqrt2$, are you worried that the equation $x^2=2$ has two solutions ?

Comment: $x=\sqrt2$ is uniquely defined by $(x\times x=2)\land\exists c\in\Bbb R(c\times c=x)$. So there is a fundamental difference between $\sqrt2$ and $-\sqrt2$.

Comment: Who does put -1 without explaining why? I see this comment as not impertinent. (By the way, the mathematical reason $\mathbb{C}$ has not a total order like $\mathbb{R}$, is precisely because -1 is a square in $\mathbb{C}$)

Comment: @columbus8myhw: right, $\sqrt 2$ is the only root of $x^2-2=0$ that is positive. $i$ is the only root of $x^2+1=0$ that has a positive imaginary part. So there is a fundamental difference between $i$ and $-i$.

Comment: @YvesDaoust True enough. (But only in a language that can describe such things.) I wasn't the downvoter, by the way.